# Search Function in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello Guys Please Help me with my Search code, currently this code below i can search only using( Last Name) is there anyway i could add more search option Like (Age or level)on the same (text box) using overload function

This is my Code

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
    {
        var tbl_Student1 = db.tbl_Student1.Include(t => t.tbl_Class);
        return View(tbl_Student1.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(search) || search == null).ToList());
    }
```

Comment: `.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(search) || x.Age == [something] || x.Level == [something] || search == null)` - just expand your condition to contain or-condition based from `x`.

Comment: Bro. erorr on this line []

Comment: `[something]` are just markers to mark your comparison values should take place - don't copy it verbatim (change those markers to actual values you want, since you don't provide what criteria you're being set with in question).

Comment: i want to add Level and Age but even when i remove the [] still having error

Comment: your a genius bro got it :)